# Django and IP limitation

Tags: django, location, ip

I want to limit my site to USA plus several outside-US IP adrresses (developers, QA etc..). And beside these, I want to display template saying "Coming soon to your country".

I'm curious if there's any easy or already developed plugin for this.

Comment: It will probably depend on the webserver you are using. Do you mean just from "runserver"? Or are you already running Tornado, Twisted Web, Apache?

Answer (score 1):

In Django the simplest way would be to use [GeoIP](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/) and custom middleware to check every request.

Answer (score 0):

On the Django level you can use [GeoIP](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/) application from GeoDjango (thanks to ArturM).

But it's better do this on webserver level for performance purpose. If you are using ngingx, try [HttpGeoIPModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGeoIPModule). For apache - [libapache2-mod-geoip](http://www.debiantutorials.com/installing-the-geoip-apache-module/)